# underscore template - jQuery object reference

Tags: jquery, underscore.js, template-engine

Somewhere in my template I need to render a chart:

```
{{= new App.components.Doughnut() }}
```

And the `Doughnut` constructor returns a string of the compiled template, but inside the logic of `Doughnut`, I have a timeout which changes it's the chart value. Problem is, I have no way of internally saving the instance, to access it later, since it is converted to a string and printed as part of the compiled template, the instance is lost.

I have countless places where it's written:

```
{{= new App.components.Doughnut({radius:50,50}).render() }}
```

Is there a way to somehow save the reference to the instance from inside the factory, so later I could access it?

I thought maybe somehow putting placeholders (with their own settings) in the template, so only after it was compiled, the instances will be appended to each placeholder.

```
App.components.Doughnut = function(settings = {}){
    var template = _.template(templates["components\\plotting\\doughnut"]);
    this.settings = $.extend({}, { radius:[70,70]}, settings);
    this.compiledTemplate = template(this.settings);
    this.doughnut = $(this.compiledTemplate);
};

App.components.Doughnut.prototype = {
    render : function(){
        // animate the value with delay
        setTimeout( this.setValue.bind(this), 1000 );
        return this.compiledTemplate;
    },

    setValue: function (value = this.settings.value){
        // do something 
        this.doughnut.doSomething()
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Ended up write this inside my template:

```
<script type='js/template-doughnut'>
   {"value" : 80}
</script>
```

Then in the template controller, I write:

```
$target.find('script[type="js/template-doughnut"]').each(function(){
    try{
        var data = JSON.parse(this.innerHTML),
            doughnut = new App.components.Doughnut( data );
        // This way reference to the element is saved
        $(this).replaceWith(doughnut.elm); 
    }
    catch(err){}
})
```